# Smarty Date and time Compare

Tags: php, date, templates, smarty

I Can't for the life of me find a way to compare dates with times in Smarty template.

Dates alone work perfect but the second you add hours it falls over:

```
{if $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" > '2015/12/10 12:00'} 
greater 2015/12/10 12:00- {$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"}
{else}
smaller 2015/12/10 12:00- {$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"}
{/if}
```

date_format is meant to be a wrapper for strtotime hence the compare should work with times as well as dates?

DATE works like this no problem :

```
{if $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y/%m/%d" > '2015/12/10'} 
greater 2015/12/10- {$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y/%m/%d"}
{else}
smaller 2015/12/10- {$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y/%m/%d"}
{/if}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Smarty isn't doing date math. This is a string compare.
Changing "2015-12-10 12:00:00" into "20151210120000" should sort/compare the way you're expecting.

Something like this:

```
{assign var="simpleDate" value="2015-12-10 12:00:00"}
{if $testDate:date_format:"%Y%m%d%H%m%S" > $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y%m%d%H%m%S"}Greater Than{/if}
{if $testDate|date_format:"%Y%m%d%H%m%S" < $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y%m%d%H%m%S"}Less Than{/if}
```

Make sure you preserve those leading zeros in the compare. It doesn't work without them.

The date format details can be found here.
https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format